# Make a new notification with sound icon and bar

Tags: unity, sound, pulseaudio, bluetooth, notification

Probably this question has already been answered somewhere, but I could not find it.

The situation: I am on Ubuntu 15.10, on a laptop.
I have a secondary bluetooth speakers system, on which I redirect some output (mainly the music).

I can control the volume with `pactl` with

```
pactl -- set-sink-volume bluez_sink.00_18_91_65_D8_6D +5%
pactl -- set-sink-volume bluez_sink.00_18_91_65_D8_6D -5%
```

and having associated this to some keyboard shortcuts I can increase and decrease it like if it'd be local.

This works fine but, unlike for the main output (the internal audio card), using this command does not produce a notification with the actual volume level.

So, how can I produce the notification with the changing icon and the bar for the volume, like Ubuntu does?

Should I use `notify-send`? With which parameters?
It should not be a "normal" notification, because it has to "stick" there when the volume changes and just adapt the bar...

Comment: No help anybody? :(

Comment: I can write you something to create a notification bubble with one of the 4 icons (volume high/medium/low/muted) and a textual representation of the volume level. But the bar is beyond my powers. Shall I write an answer with that or is this not acceptable for you yet?

Comment: Does it change by just changing the text inside without issuing another notification when you change multiple times in a row the volume? In this case yes. But if it changes by creating another notification than not, because I can do it myself :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yep, it should be special notification:

```
gdbus call --session --dest org.freedesktop.Notifications \
  --object-path /org/freedesktop/Notifications \
  --method org.freedesktop.Notifications.Notify \
    'gnome-settings-daemon' \
    0 \
    'notification-audio-volume-medium' \
    ' ' \
    '' \
    [] \
    "{'x-canonical-private-synchronous': <'volume'>, 'value': <24>}" \
    1
```

1. Found by watching `dbus-monitor`:

   ```
   method call time=1447796042.858910 sender=:1.11 -> destination=:1.96 serial=216 path=/org/freedesktop/Notifications; interface=org.freedesktop.Notifications; member=Notify
      string "gnome-settings-daemon"
      uint32 0
      string "notification-audio-volume-medium"
      string " "
      string ""
      array [
      ]
      array [
         dict entry(
            string "x-canonical-private-synchronous"
            variant             string "volume"
         )
         dict entry(
            string "value"
            variant             int32 48
         )
      ]
      int32 -1
   ```
2. Then write my own call using:

   - `gdbus` following this post [How to pass a{sv} arguments to gdbus?](https://askubuntu.com/q/359587/26246)
   - Or if you want python, this well explained post: [How to read dbus-monitor output?](https://askubuntu.com/q/38733/26246). Even it has same sound notification as a showcase.
3. Icons available are:

   `find /usr/share/notify-osd/icons/hicolor/scalable/status/ -name "notification-audio-volume-*" -exec basename {} .svg \;`

   ```
   notification-audio-volume-low
   notification-audio-volume-off
   notification-audio-volume-medium
   notification-audio-volume-muted
   notification-audio-volume-high
   ```

Comment: This is just a WOW and +1 from me. I'm impressed that you came up with a working solution that fast despite the crappy quality of official documentations for all this stuff. I'm planning to maybe write my own implementation of Python `pynotify` directly on dbus just to avoid this documentation lack and for the fun of it. I'm planning to write a better indicator interface for Python as well. You seem to have a great knowledge in this topic, may I contact you if I need help and how should I best do this?

Comment: That's it! This is just great! :D I managed to do my script and integrate it into the shortcuts, thank you very much! :D

Comment: @ByteCommander thank you all, Actually not much but I followed dbus tag for few months in AU to learn it. As it is quiet related that, explore portions of gnome-settings-daemon & indicator-sound source code in few occasions in AU too. gnome-settings-daemon has a plugin that processes sound accelerator keys. Those icons are part of notify-osd package then it's source & doc should be helpful too. You are welcome, you may ping me in AU, SO, or UL on any related post/chat or even gmail with the same emanresu :D.

Comment: Thanks, I will remember you when I start with the project. Currently I'm still busy with a Python wrapper around `appindicator`. After that I might start with the notification stuff.

Comment: @ByteCommander , could I ask why you need new libappindicator wrapper? as there is a Gnome Introspection binding already available. or do you mean libindicator?

Comment: Because I simply don't like the API and doc for both `appindicator` as well as `gi.repository.AppIndicator3`. I'm also adding some functionality.